# Displaying a multi-zoom image layer in open

Tags: openlayers-2

I am displaying an image on a map in OpenLayers. The problem is: if I zoom out, the image vanishes. If I zoom in, it works as it should. How do I display an image layer in OpenLayers so that when I zoom out, the image is still there? I guarantee this is a duplicate question but I can't seem to find the answer. So, I apologize if this has been answered.

Here is my code:

```
  var graphic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
                Monocle.currentWidget.name + " Destination " + featurenum,
                "data:image/png;base64," + results,
                new OpenLayers.Bounds(Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,1), Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,2), Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,3),Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,4)),
                new OpenLayers.Size(580, 288),
                { isBaseLayer: false,
                    opacity: 0.3,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a max resolution and then it will resize the image. So, I changed my code to:

```
var graphic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
                Monocle.currentWidget.name + " Destination " + featurenum,
                "data:image/png;base64," + results,
                new OpenLayers.Bounds(Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,1), Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,2), Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,3),Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,4)),
                new OpenLayers.Size(580, 288),
                { isBaseLayer: false,
                    opacity: 0.3,
                    transitionEffect:'resize',
                    maxResolution: .625,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true
                });
```